# Issues in Sending Email From Localhost[WAMP] in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email from wampserver "localhost", to my gmail account by using the following CodeIgniter code.

```
public function emailsent_info()
    {
        $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'XXXXXXX@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXXXX',
           );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);

    //$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('deepak.keynes@gmail.com', 'Deepak Saar');
    $this->email->to('deepak.keynes@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Matters Mostly Good');

    $this->email->message('Its Working Now, Great');

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your Email Sent Successfully';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

}
I did not do any other modifications in any other files in CI yet. While I run the Project, the server replied with the following:
[image: The Server Replied with this message]
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: localserver cannot send mail bro

Comment: @Exprator, There are some references which i saw through the net to send email through ci

Comment: you cant bro from localserver.

Comment: @Keynes Post those references.

Comment: @Tpojka, references?

Comment: @Keynes "There are some references which i saw through the net to send email through ci"

Answer (score 1):

if you are using smtp mail on local then you have to set up smtp setting of your wamp ,
if you use **PHPMAILER** it is very simple to use ,download the phpmailer [following link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and put it into library folder then crete one helper name mail_helper.php function put this code like this

```
function sendmail($email, $subject = FALSE, $message = FALSE, $headers = FALSE, $from = FROM_EMAIL) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // we are going to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enabled SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  // prefix for secure protocol to connect to the server
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;      // setting GMail as our SMTP server
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;                   // SMTP port to connect to GMail
    $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;  // user email address
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;            // password in GMail
    if ($from != FALSE)
        $mail->SetFrom($from, FROM_EMAIL);  //Who is sending the email

// $mail->AddReplyTo("ign@ignisitsolutions.com","Firstname Lastname");  //email address that receives the response
    if ($subject != FALSE) {
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
    }
    if ($message != FALSE) {
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->AltBody = $message;
    }

    if (is_array($email) && count($email) > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($email); $i++) {
            $destino = $email[$i]; // Who is addressed the email to

            $mail->AddAddress($destino, $destino);
        }
    } else {
        $destino = $email; // Who is addressed the email to
        $mail->AddAddress($destino, $destino);
    }

    //    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // some attached files
    //    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // as many as you want
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

and load the helper and use this helper like this

```
sendmail("test@test.com","Test Subject", "This is test", $headers = FALSE,  FROM_EMAIL)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use PHPMailer in Code Igniter..? If So, Where Should I place the PHPMailer inside the CI 3.0..?

Comment: yes it is possible and simple .download phpmailer from above link and put folder in library folder and create one helper like above i gave a code .

Comment: Can you explain me in detail, how to put inside library folder and create helper file . can you help me step by step..?

Comment: I found it but there is an easy way to do it in CI Itself..!

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an e-mail from your localhost without some configurations,

I personally use [SMTP4DEV](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) when I'm coding in a localhost,

If you insist on sending real e-mails, this may help you out: [CONFIGURE SENDMAIL WITH WAMP](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp)